# How can I change code in hector_slam?

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, hector-slam, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Today I have 2 questions. 1º: Where is the file with the Particle filter, or similar, in Hector_SLAM? I suppose that it is connected with hector_mapping but I don´t find the file.
2º: Can I change the number of particles used for Hector_SLAM? In gmapping we use the parameter "particle". If this is possible, where is this data?
Thanks for all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128626/how-can-i-change-code-in-hector_slam?/) by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2014-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hector_mapping does not use a particle filter, but pose estimation using fast scanmatching that is accurate enough to not require multiple hypotheses (such as in a rao-blackwellized particle filter approach like gmapping) in many real world applications. Thus, there is no particle count that you could increase. You could take a shot at adding a particle filter implementation on top of hector_mapping of course, but that´s a non-trivial change.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) on 2014-02-12**:
Thanks other time for the answer. Can you tell me where is the file that use this scanmatchig? I want study it. Do a pre-filter not is my solution. Thanks.